# There is a hole in my ground in Terraria that keeps reappearing!

Tags: terraria

Okay so I made a new world and I started building a house and making the land flat. I then decided to leave my new world to go back to my old world to collect stuff to bring over and I did not have enough inventory room so I dropped/threw a whole bunch of my stuff on the ground (I did not place it like you are supposed to). Anyways when I left my new world and got my stuff from my old world I returned and where I dropped/threw all my stuff was now an empty shallow hole in the ground in the middle of my house.

Now every time I patch it up and exit the game and go to play again later the hole is back and my patchwork has disappeared. What went wrong? I really don't want to tear down my house that I have already built so much of.

Comment: Did you ever set a bed as your spawn point?

Comment: No not yet, But I see what you are getting at because that is where I end up whenever I die or go to the world. I just went and set a new spawn point saved and exited then entered again and my patchwork stayed. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: No problem! I ran into that quite a lot while playing. I've posted the explanation/solution as an answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was that, if you accidentally build over your spawn point, it will destroy any blocks in the way when you respawn. To solve this, either bind your spawn point to a bed somewhere, or just leave that hole there for the time being.

Comment: I had that happen so many times.  My fix for it was to make a room big enough that the spawn would leave the blocks alone.  Or move the house so the spawn was just outside.  It took a little experimentation.

Comment: This finally explains it. I had a world where I would instantly die and form a hole in the ground one block deep that kept reappearing after I leave and come back.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use 3rd party software to move the spawn point.  I did this for a map I turned into a server so new players/characters wouldn't wreck my house.

One program you can use is [TEdit](http://www.example.com/). In the default view the tool you need is the button 3rd from the bottom on the left side (vertical) tool bar.

Comment: What third party software would you use?  How would you use it to accomplish the task?

Comment: I listed an example.  I figured it was biased and people wouldn't want to use third party when I answered this, so I didn't include it then.